# I can't get my Angular code to show in my HTML page

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm pretty much a beginner to Angular, and although I looked at a few things, I can't figure out why my code won't correctly display on my page.

My html is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

 <body ng-app="MyApp">
     <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <h1> {{ title }} </h1>
     </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Meanwhile, my angular controller looks like this:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.title: "My favourite movies...so far";

 $scope.movies = 
 [
   {... etc } 
 ]
```

And my angular module looks like this:

```
 var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
```

I'm pretty much a huge newb at this, what exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check your console, you have syntax errors. FYI ~ `$scope.title = 'My favourite...`, `=`, not `:`. Can't see where you've included your app script either

Comment: Check your script src. Using `//ajax....` won't work if you aren't running off an HTTP server

Comment: Have you included your controller javascript file in your html?

Comment: I replaced the " : ", my mistake! Fixed the spacing and the shitty " //ajax.." as well! @JonathonBlok 

I have my controller in another file in another folder in the directory, might that be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo on your code that most probably is stopping all the execution;

Replace:

```
$scope.title: "My favourite movies...so far";
```

With:

```
$scope.title = "My favourite movies...so far";
```

Comment: There's a specific *"close question"* vote for typos as the questions (and subsequent answers) don't really help anyone